# How to disable home key in android 12?

Tags: android, kotlin

In the 12 android version cannot control home button key or hide it, I searched about it too much but unfortunately couldn't fix it

Do you have any solutions ?

Comment: Fortunately, ordinary apps cannot do this.

Comment: It's not up to individual apps to do this. But you can look up "kiosk mode" for devices that are used in a setting where leaving an app should be disabled.

Comment: i found an app that do it : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adriadevs.screenlock.ios.keypad.timepassword